# jwplayer in recyclerview throwing illegalstateexception when it loses focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, jwplayer

I am trying to implement facebook scroll behaviour in videos with jwplayer. But when the focus loses the playerview is showing illegalstateexception. Can anyone please help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">

    <com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView
        xmlns:jwp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.longtailvideo.jwplayer"
        android:id="@+id/jwplayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        jwp:jw_autostart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Test :: Facebook Video Player"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jwplayer" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@id/facebook"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With a RecyclerAdapter and ViewHolder I am trying to load video in the playerview. The illegalexception is showing inside the playerview as text when I scroll down and the focus lost.

Comment: can you post error and your code here

Comment: Please see the above code

Comment: Java code and your error too

Comment: It is not throwing error from the java code, it is showing error in the playerview

Comment: http://jwplayer57.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=55698014&item=662. This is the issue I am facing, it is reported in jwplayer forum but nobody answered